# About resolve method of the java.nio.Path

Tags: java, file, io, nio

I thoroughly understand the use of resolve(path) and relativize(path).
In the following snippet though there is something which is not very clear to me:

```
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attr) throws IOException
        {

        destinationFolder = destinationFolder.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
        Files.copy(dir, destinationFolder,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
```

This snippet has been taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java) (preVisitDirectory method). I have slightly modified it as for changing name of `target` to `destinationFolder`.

If destinationFolder is `/home/user/Desktop/Destination` and source and dir (at least for the first recursive call) are `/home/user/Desktop/ToBeCopied`.

The result of destinationFolder will be `/home/user/Desktop/Destination`. 
This works fine and it is supercool however I cannot see why it gives back this outcome since `source.relativize(dir)`; returns `../ToBeCopied` and then with `destinationFolder.resolve(../ToBeCopied)` it should return (without normalizing it) `/home/user/Desktop/Destination/../ToBeCopied` hence `/home/user/Desktop/ToBeCopied`.
Now if it was the case my program would not work, `/ToBeCopied` would self copy itself (if it makes sense). What actually happens is that in somehow the system takes the relative pattern used in `source.relativize(dir)` which is `../ToBeCopied` and read something like "go back one step and then comeback" not like "go back one step and then back to `/ToBeCopied`". Why does it happen though? Logically should give back `/home/user/Desktop/Destination/../ToBeCopied` instead it returns `/home/user/Desktop/Destination`. What am I missing?
Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: `dir` is the current directory of the recursive method `preVisitDirectory` and the first call will be exactly the same as the source itself.

Comment: It appears you are altering `destinationFolder` each time preVisitDirectory is called.  Was that your intent?

Comment: the intent is implementing this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java . Everything is working I just do not get why it works in that way. And I would like to know why.

Comment: The Oracle example calls `target.resolve(source.relativize(dir))`.  Notice that `target` never changes.  You, on the other hand, are changing the variable that `resolve` is called on (namely, `destinationFolder`).  So you will not end up with a correctly copied directory structure.

Comment: @VGR I tried it out and it works fine. target at his original state it's useful only at the first recursive call. However it's not my point the point is that source.resolve(dir) at the first recursive call, returns ../source but in the Path newDir actually get stored ../target  and I do not know why it works in this way. Again the point I do not understand is "newDir = target.resolve(source.relativize(dir));" considering that target is /home/user/Desktop/Target when resolved to "source.relativize(dir))" (which is ../source) it should gives back /home/user/Desktop/target/../source.